# while loop align columns

Tags: perl, alignment

hi 
I wrote a perl script where I stored columns from a text file filled with ip and port scans into variables.  The variables contain many ip addreses, ports, protocols, states, and services now I need a while loop that takes all the ip's stored in the ip variable and  matches them with its corresponding ports protocols and state etc.side by side look so:
192.168.3 45 tcp open smtp

heres my code

```
$ip_address = `cat /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/test11.txt | 
    grep 'Nmap scan report for'`;

$state = `cat /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/test11.txt | grep -v 'PORT'|
    grep -v 'filtered'| grep -v 'latency'| grep -v 'Nmap' | grep -v 'Discovered' |
    grep -v 'Raw' | grep -v 'SYN' | grep -v 'DNS'| grep -v 'Ping' | 
    grep -v 'Scanning' `;

$port = `cat /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/test11.txt | grep -v  'Discovered'| 
    grep -v 'Nmap' | grep -v 'PORT' | grep -v 'ports'| grep -v 'Read' | 
    grep -v 'Raw'| grep -v 'Completed'| grep -v 'DNS' | grep -v 'hosts' | 
    grep -v 'Ping' | grep -v 'SYN' | grep -v 'latency' `;

$protocol = `cat /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/test11.txt | grep -v  'Discovered'| 
    grep -v 'Nmap' | grep -v 'PORT' | grep -v 'ports'| grep -v 'Read' | 
    grep -v 'Raw' | grep -v 'Completed'| grep -v 'DNS' | grep -v 'hosts' | 
    grep -v 'Ping' | grep -v 'SYN' | grep -v 'latency' `;
{

$service = `cat /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/test11.txt | grep -v 'Nmap' | 
    grep-v 'Host' | grep -v 'filtered' | grep -v 'PORT' | grep -v 'Raw'| 
    grep -v 'Scanning'| grep -v 'Completed'| grep -v 'Ping' |grep -v 'DNS' | 
    grep -v 'Discovered'| grep -v 'SYN'`;

while($ip_address, $port, $protocol, $state, #service)
{
    chomp ($ip_address, $port, $protocol, $state, #service);
    print "$ip_address, $port, $protocol, $state, #service";
    exit 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know about the -oG flag for nmap right? It makes parsing the output a lot easier. Also there's -oX which outputs XML, which is even easier to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I say to use the tools that you understand and that it's OK to do things like call `awk` from Perl. But for this code I'll make an exception. You should be using the builtin `Perl` commands for this task. Namely, arrays and Perl's `grep` operator. Here's how I would start to rewrite this.

```
# do this once instead of `cat ...` several times.
open my $fh, '<', '/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/test11.txt';
my @the_input = <$fh>;
close $fh;

# do this instead of `| grep -v ... | grep -v ...`
my @ip_addresses = grep { /Nmap scan report for/ } @the_input;
my @states = grep { 
    !/PORT|filtered|latency|Nmap|Discovered|Raw|SYN|DNS|Ping|Scanning/
} @the_input;
my @ports = grep {
    !/Discovered|Nmap|PORT|ports|Read|Raw|Completed|DNS|hosts|Ping|SYN|latency/
} @the_input;
my @protocols = grep {
    !/Discovered|Nmap|PORT|ports|Read|Raw|Completed|DNS|hosts|Ping|SYN|latency/
} @the_input;
my @services = grep {
    !/Nmap|Host|filtered|PORT|Raw|Scanning|Completed|Ping|DNS|Discovered|SYN/
} @the_input;
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to do these sorts of things in one pass, like...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(F, "/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/test11.txt");

while(<F>) {

  # If the current line has something that matches an IP
  # address, store the matched pattern in $ip. We'll
  # use this as we process the remaining lines.
  #
  $ip = $1 if ( /Nmap scan report for (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ );

  # Try to match lines like "ddd/www www www wwww"
  #
  ( $port, $protocol, $state, $service) = ( m|(\d+)/(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)| );

  print "$ip, $port, $protocol, $state, $service\n" if $port;

}
```